# send command to server using QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, curl, qt5, qprocess

I made simple example using QProcess. 

Just get json value from DBpedia server. 

 **Q.How can make command using QProcess?**

Original command

```
curl -s "http://dbpedia.org/data/Haeinsa.json"| perl dbpediaPlaceData.txt 'Haeinsa'
```

#### My code

1. get JSON value from DBPedia server

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QFileInfo>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString command="curl";
    QProcess pro;
    QStringList arg;
    arg.append("-v");
    arg.append("--insecure");
    arg.append("GET");
    arg.append("http://dbpedia.org/data/Haeinsa.json");

    pro.execute(command,arg);
    pro.start(command);
    pro.waitForStarted();
    pro.waitForReadyRead();
    pro.waitForFinished();

    QByteArray qa=pro.readAll();
    QString reply=QString::fromUtf8(qa);
    qDebug() << reply;

    return a.exec();
}
```

2.  perl dbpediaPlaceData.txt 'Haeinsa'

```
void processPerl()
{
    QString command = "perl";
    QString fileName ="/Users/yoshimi/dbpediaPlaceData.txt ";
    QString cmd = "perl" + fileName + "Haeinsa";

    QProcess* process_screen = new QProcess();
    process_screen->start(cmd);

    process_screen->waitForStarted();
    QByteArray q=process_screen->readAll();
    QString replyB=QString::fromUtf8(q);
    qDebug() << replyB;

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Any reason to rely on `curl` when Qt has a perfectly good network API built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to implement the command using `QProcess`, so the main difficulty is to implement the pipe: `|`, in this case you must use `setStandardOutputProcess()`:

```
QProcess curlProcess;
QProcess perlProcess;
QString filename = "/Users/yoshimi/Music/cridb/dbpediaPlaceData/dbpediaPlaceData.txt";
curlProcess.setStandardOutputProcess(&perlProcess);
curlProcess.start("curl", {"-s", "http://dbpedia.org/data/Haeinsa.json"});
if (curlProcess.waitForFinished()){
    perlProcess.start("perl", { filename, "Haeinsa"});
    if(perlProcess.waitForFinished()){
        qDebug()<< perlProcess.readAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: perlProcess.readAll() don't bring data.</br>
When I test on terminal, Json data show on terminal.
```
yoshimi~/Music/cridb/dbpediaPlaceData$ curl -s "http://dbpedia.org/data/Haeinsa.json"
 | perl dbpediaPlaceData.txt 'Haeinsa'

  "command": "save",
  "record_type": "thing",
  "data": {
    "lat": 35.7999992370605,
    "subtype": "place",
    "name": "Haeinsa",
    "long": 128.100006103516,
    "notes": "wkpd-Haeinsa"
  }
```

Comment: @Sunmi try again

Comment: I build and but terminal don't show data. I put function on int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  } .

Comment: @Sunmi copy and try again please. :)

Comment: @Sunmi  `QString filename = "dbpediaPlaceData.txt";` to `QString filename = "/full/path/of/dbpediaPlaceData.txt"`

Comment: Your answer help me lots !